# Python kbhit() problems

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a very simple program that will wait for x seconds before checking to see it a key has been pressed then, depending on this outcome will go into a different loop further down the code. I have this code:

```
import msvcrt
import time
import sys

time.sleep(1)
if msvcrt.kbhit():
    sys.stdout.write('y')
else:
    sys.stdout.write('n')
```

So I press any key when it first starts (making kbhit ==true) but it always just falls to the second statement and prints 'n'. 
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

{Using Python 2.7 and IDLE}

Thanks

Comment: Did you read: [Does being on-topic at another StackExchange site automatically make a question off-topic for StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/510937) ?

Comment: Good link, but the text its in confuses me

Answer (score 10):

The `msvcrt.kbhit()` function will only work if the program it is in has been run from the windows command line (or if a console window is opened for its input and output when you double click on its `.py` file).

If you run from IDLE or using the `pythonw.exe` interpreter, the program won't be connected to a console window and the [console-IO commands](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) from `msvcrt` won't work.